# Android studio: AVP Crashing when update Google Play

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm really stuck here.  Brand new install on linux .  SDK platform is Q.
I create a virtual device and choose on e with the Play store logo.  Pixel 2 , Nexus 5.
All good
I activate and the device pops up.  I select more options(...)Location is working great. I select Google play. Now it displays "Loading.."  forever.   If I click update. It crashes with the following error.  "There was an unknown error while opening Google Play services Page."
????
Has anyone seen this.  Any idea what i can try?